# lambda way to assign a value

Tags: python, lambda

In my python code, I want to assign the "name" value into "**request_body**" based on the input, something as if:

```
def make_api_call(context, name, ...):
    api_name = f"<my_API_Call_URL_here>"
    request_body= {}
    request_body["name"] = lambda name:  "" if name == "BLANK" else name
    ...
    context.base.execution_call(context, api_name, request_body, "post")
```

Is that the correct way in lambda to have the string value assigned to **request_body["name"]**?

Somehow, when I to make the api call in the end, I have got such error message:

```
TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: There’s no need for the lambda at all. Just use `request_body["name"] = "" if name == "BLANK" else name`

Comment: You are basically assigning a function to the `name` key, and not a value. As mentioned earlier, the `lambda` is not necessary.

Comment: yes, I can use the If/else way to do it, but I just want to have the code looks neat.

Comment: @user3595231, what do you mean looks neat? It doesn't do what you are intending to do.

Comment: Python isn’t about ‘looks neat’.  It’s about *clear* and concise code which is easy to read and efficient.

Comment: @navneethc While true that it ultimately does not work, I can assure you that that support for self-executing functions/lambdas can make things much tidier (imho). I suspect the OP comes from such a language (like say javascript) where this is possible

Comment: @S3DEV is it not the case that a neat and tidy code is also likely to be clear and concise? That would seem to me to be the entire point.

Comment: @JonSG - Agreed, neat and tidy code is likely to be clear and concise.  However, this is neither and unnecessary - no need for a function to store the if/else. **Especially** if the purpose is ‘because it looks neat’.

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding of how lambda being used. Thanks for all the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) is an alternative way to create a small function and there's no need for it in your case. You should use something like:

```
request_body["name"] = "" if name == "BLANK" else name
```

You can't use a lambda to "assign a value" without calling it:

```
>>> a = lambda name: "" if name == "BLANK" else name
>>> type(a)
<class 'function'>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you want to say just that *You can't use a lambda to "assign a value"* because I can clearly "use a lambda to assign a value" by calling it.

Comment: Yep, fair enough

Answer (score 0):

if you want your lambda that bad try this

```
test_name = lambda x:  "" if x == "BLANK" else x
request_body["name"] = test_name(name)
```